If rsync can't link what does it do?
I am using BackInTime for backing up my files. I am getting a bunch of errors of the following form:
Error: rsync: link "previous_backup_file" => "current_backup_file" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
Question 1: why am I getting this error?
Question 2: what is the default behaviour of rsync in this situation? Is it just going to create a new copy of the file instead of linking it? It seems so to me, because when I browse the current backup (where errors occurred), I can actually see the files that threw the errors there.


check your options for BackInTime https://backintime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#options 2) You can check defaults of rysnc on the man page (but beware that rsync is so ubiquitous and has so many options that I would not be surprised if different distros may ship it with different defaults). Your link .... is a symlink, a hard link? a windows shortcut? Previous backup file is a weird file name ... it suggests more the backup itself than the files being backed up. Seems a little like more to the story here.


As to why you are getting this error - not enough info to say here. Could be permissions, could be the file systems you are using don't support the links, could be the operation itself isn't something rsync supports - not sure, but given these file names maybe doing something weird like copying the backup into itself recursively.

@topsail well, I'm not including my actual file name because I think that's irrelevant and would make the error message less readable, but just in case I will mention that it is mainly .jpg files that are getting the error (but not all of them!). I don't know what my link is, the error literally says link.

@topsail I did not find info on the man page regarding the behaviour under this linking error. Did you?

I'm wondering why are all these apps for linux so unusable? Like is there any linux app that just works as you expect? I mean it's a pretty simple task: back-up-the-files. Like all it has to do is back up the files. How difficult can that be? Why is it throwing 200 errors with completely obscure messages which are not even documented what happens in this case? A backup is supposed to make it easier to keep files, not become an additional burden...

The man page was for you to understand the settings more than to look for your error message. There is a section at the bottom specifically summarizing how links are treated - that may help you. Backups are supposed to be easy? If that were true, all the hundreds of millions of people who don't back up their files would be doing it.

I would suggest you browse/search a forum where you can seek advice and get opinions on the easiest backup apps (I use rsync directly myself, which took a bit of working out the kinks).

I have to warn you that Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions (i.e. writing code, rather than using backup utilities). This question will likely be closed as off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See What topics can I ask about here in the Help Center. Perhaps Super User or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange would be a better place to ask (personally I like https://AskUbuntu.com for linux questions - although I get warned too if not directly Ubuntu stuff).

I used to backup my home directly by using a tar command to just zip the whole thing up. I can only tell you that yes, backups can be easy. Also they can be hard. Some backup apps work great (for some people or for experts) others are hard to use (for some people or non-experts). You have to try some different things, find out what works for you, and possibly spend time getting the options and configuration all worked out.
